# conditionally change an HTML tag at the same level depending on a condition

Tags: reactjs

I have this block of code

```
const route="";
return (
    <Link to={route}>
     </p>{route?'click':'No click'}
    </Link>
  )
```

I want that if the `route` variable contains something, I want `<Link>` to enclose the `<p>`, but otherwise I want a `<>` to close it.
example:

```
const route="/home";
return (
    <Link to="/home">
      <p>click</p>
    </Link>
  )

const route="";
return (
    <>
     <p>No click</p>
    </>
  )
```

How can I do this?

I was thinking of something like this, but I know it doesn't make sense.

```
{route && <Link>
  <p> 
</Link>}
```

**Note: the `p` tag is an example, there I can have many components so the idea is not to duplicate code.**

```
    <Link to="/home">
      <ComponentA/>
      <ComponentB/>
      <ComponentC styles{mystyles}/>
      {var && <ComponentD/>}
      <ComponentE/>
      <ComponentF/>
    </Link>
```

Comment: The problem is that React doesn't deal with _tags_, it deals with elements and components. You shouldn't seek to write convoluted logic to output specific _markup_. You should output components or just elements. (This is true for JavaScript in general, not just React.)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. The simplest way would be something like

```
{route === something ? (
  <Link><p>Click</p></Link>
) : (
  <p>No Click</p>
)}
```

If you have a lot of content and really want to go the DRY route, you could always create a helper function that returns the content like so:

```
const getContent = hasRoute => <p>{hasRoute ? 'Click' : 'No click'}</p>
const hasRoute = !!route
{hasRoute ? <Link>{getContent(hasRoute)}</Link> : getContent(hasRoute)}
```

Finally, for maximum reusability, I guess you could just create a `<NoLink>` wrapper element around a normal paragraph, and dynamically set a `<Container>` alias to either `<Link>` or `<NoLink>` and it should work fine:

```
const isLink = !!route
const NoLink = ({children}) => <p>{children}</p>
const Content = isLink ? Link : NoLink
return (
  <Content>
    {isLink ? 'Click' : 'No Link'}
  </Content>
)
```

Personally, if it's just a small amount of content, I would go with the first approach to reduce code complexity since the 2nd and 3rd add needlessly larger amounts of mental loopholes to understand what you're doing. And only make sense with larger amounts of content.

Also, keep in mind that the fragment you added (`<></>`) [does nothing when you are only returning a single childlike in your example](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). It's only necessary when you are returning more than one child.

Comment: thanks...the idea is not generate duplicity :/ . I only need change the HTML tag

Comment: I updated by answer on how to avoid duplicated code. Keep in mind that T-DRY (Try to Don't Repeat Yourself) is sometimes better than going full-on DRY for the sake of code readability. Sometimes DRY adds unnecessary complexity for the sake of avoiding code duplication. In this case, either solution can work depending on the size of your content.

Comment: Or take a [WET](https://dev.to/wuz/stop-trying-to-be-so-dry-instead-write-everything-twice-wet-5g33) approach, which I personally prefer (for readability and often for code reduction).

Comment: x2 on WET, and it's why I prefer T-DRY over DRY or WET. It's a nice compromise between both :)

Comment: I added a single final approach (making a total of 3 approaches), and clarification on how to pick one @yavgz

Answer (score 0):

```
{route && route != '' ? <Link>
  <p> 
</Link> : null}
```

Comment: the `null` part is not required, just `{route && route != '' && <>...<>}` is enough

Answer (score 0):

```
{route ? (
    <Link to={route}><p>...</p></Link>
  ) : (
    <p>...</p>
  )
}
```

If the contents of the `p` tag are the same on either occasion you could also assign those content to a variable to make the code the slightest bit more DRY:

```
const content = <p>...</p>;

return ({route ? (
    <Link to={route}>{content}</Link>
  ) : (
    content
  )
});
```